# Can iOS applications be targeted to certain users in the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I've written an enterprise iPhone app for the field workers in our company, and the powers-that-be are considering offering it to some of our client companies as a freebie for their field workers to use. I assume that Apple would not allow enterprise distribution to users who are not company employees, so I would have to place it on the App Store.

However, we would like to restrict the user base to approved users or companies, so I would like to avoid making it available to just anyone. The app does communicate with our servers, which makes it something of a risk, in my opinion, of hacking; we'd certainly like to avoid that.

I'm wondering if there is a way to restrict App Store downloads only to certain users or companies? Or is there an alternative method to prevent just anyone from downloading and using the app?

Comment: Off-topic for Stack Overflow, but... you probably want to look at Business-to-Business distribution: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: Have you tried TestFlight?

Comment: @DonMag This appears to be exactly what I need! If you'll submit that as an answer, I'll accept it. BTW, it occurred to me only after I posted this that it may not be appropriate for SO. I was trying to figure out what to do about it when I saw your response. Thanks!

Comment: @mcgtrt Never heard of it, but I looked it up. That would be a good choice except it appears that there is only a 90 day window that apps are useable -- unless I am misunderstanding something. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the off-topic --- since two tags that came up were about the App Store, particularly appstore-approval, it may not be so off-topic as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer, as per the OP...

For your case, you probably want to look at Business-to-Business distribution: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new "DeviceCheck APIs" that is release in iOS11

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs,
>   you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining
>   user privacy. You might use this data to identify devices that have
>   already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide, or to
>   flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent. The DeviceCheck
>   APIs also let you verify that the token you receive comes from an
>   authentic Apple device on which your app has been downloaded.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck